# Managing user disk space

Tags: 7, files

I need a mechanism for managing users' storage space.  I have multiple content types with file upload fields.  Admin should be able to set it globally, or per individual user.

My initial approach is to add a field in the admin configuration menu, for admin to set the default limit, and a field for users for individual space allocations.

When a user goes to create new content, I check their used space to see if they are maxed out.  Then when they are about to upload a file, I'll check the file size and see if it will put the user over the limit.  If not, I let the upload occur.

The Drupal API gives us a file_space_used() function, which gives the total file space used by a particular user, so that's pretty cool.

Am I on the right track?

EDIT AFTER ANSWER: syd asked me to post my script, and I forgot.

```
function mymod_file_validate($file)
{
    global $user;
    $ulimit = 0;    // user limit


    // get the limits per role (I had two to check against, and vals are
    // in megabytes (hence the *1000000))
    if (array_search(HL_ROLE_REG, $user->roles))
        $ulimit = variable_get(HL_VARKEY_REGSPACE) * 1000000;

    if (array_search(HL_ROLE_PREM, $user->roles))
        $ulimit = variable_get(HL_VARKEY_PREMSPACE) * 1000000;

    return (file_validate_size($file, 0, $ulimit));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal does all the work.

I made a call to file_validate_size() in my hook_file_validate() handler.  I also made an admin form to modify each role's allowable space (using variable_get/set), and it works great.

Next step is to create a table containing non-default values (keyed by uid), and an admin tool to set individual users' allowable space.  I'll then update my hook_file_validate() handler to check for the user in that table.  If not, then check the default.

Comment: Hi Vintorg, may you post the script please?

Comment: I will. Can you tell me how to format my script in this comment window?

Comment: Edit your answer or your question. It's easier.

Comment: I added my code at the top.  Sorry for the late response, but I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use [file_validate_size()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_validate_size/7)

```
function file_validate_size(stdClass $file, $file_limit = 0, $user_limit = 0) {
  global $user;

  $errors = array();

  // Bypass validation for uid  = 1.
  if ($user->uid != 1) {
    if ($file_limit && $file->filesize > $file_limit) {
      $errors[] = t('The file is %filesize exceeding the maximum file size of %maxsize.', array('%filesize' => format_size($file->filesize), '%maxsize' => format_size($file_limit)));
    }

    // Save a query by only calling file_space_used() when a limit is provided.
    if ($user_limit && (file_space_used($user->uid) + $file->filesize) > $user_limit) {
      $errors[] = t('The file is %filesize which would exceed your disk quota of %quota.', array('%filesize' => format_size($file->filesize), '%quota' => format_size($user_limit)));
    }
  }
  return $errors;
}
```

> Checks that the file's size is below certain limits.
>
> This check is not enforced for the user #1. Parameters
>
> $file: A Drupal file object.
>
> $file_limit: An integer specifying the maximum file size in bytes.
>   Zero indicates that no limit should be enforced.
>
> $user_limit: An integer specifying the maximum number of bytes the
>   user is allowed. Zero indicates that no limit should be enforced.
>   Return value
>
> An array. If the file size exceeds limits, it will contain an error
>   message.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the way to do it.  What I'm thinking about is how to store a field for the user entity.  I am trying to avoid creating a new table if possible and utilize what Drupal offers me.

Comment: I'm thinking I will set the default value in the DB using variable_set().  On the user side, I want to hide it from the users, so it looks like I'll create a table holding any non-default values.